# undeclared mixin when @import from node_modules with ~

Tags: sass, visual-studio-2022

I am using Visual Studio 2022. When I do something like

```
@import '~@my-scoped/package/styles.scss';

@include package-mixin();
```

Visual Studio will tell me that `package-mixin` is an "undeclared mixin". This compiles just fine with `sass`. It's only if I use relative paths like

```
@import '../../node_modules/@my-scoped/package/styles.scss';
```

will it then be fine with the mixin.

How can I get VS to behave like the sass compiler itself and be ok with this syntax (and get intellisense back)?

Comment: Hard to know without a little more info about your project, but if you have (or can add) a Babel config, you probably just need to set up an alias in Babel with something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-module-resolver.

Comment: I think I understand the problem better now. `~` isn't a built in sass thing, it's some sugar added by the `sass-loader` in webpack. The problem is that VS doesn't know about that which is fair. I just thought it was build into sass in which case I was expecting VS to figure it out.